# update state of duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

I want to do this:

| id | desc | status | con |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hi | 2 | b |
| 2 | hi | 2 | b |
| 3 | hell | 2 | b |
| 4 | hell | 2 | b |
| 5 | hell | 3 | c |

Imagin I have above table
First I want to find rows that where = b, then change the status of one row that have the same 'desc' to 1
My result should be like the below table:

| id | desc | status | con |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hi | 2 | b |
| 2 | hi | 1 | b |
| 3 | hell | 2 | b |
| 4 | hell | 1 | b |
| 5 | hell | 3 | c |

Comment: _change status of one row that have same 'desc' to 1_ --> you just want to change one row but if there are many how do you define the one changed? Is it random??

Comment: desc and where are both reserved words - just saying..

Comment: Do you have mysql 8 ?

Comment: @P.Salmon it's just some name I create to describe my problem. I tried to say my problem with a simple sample.

Comment: @ThomasG No it's 5.7
And for first comment: in my case doesn't matter and just want to delete one of them

Comment: @vahidghasemi in the comments you are asking another thing. You want to keep only one record for each distinct `desc` column  `where = b  ` ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha No, I don't want to delete another. I want to change the status. Isn't clear in the two tables?

Comment: @vahidghasemi then what does this comment means `No it's 5.7 And for first comment: in my case doesn't matter and just want to delete one of them` ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha :|:| He asked 'Do you have MySQL 8', I said no, And In the first comment he asked something and I answered that. I don't know what is the problem? :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
CREATE VIEW tableView AS SELECT id FROM Table WHERE con = 'b' GROUP BY desc;
UPDATE Table SET `status` = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM tableView)
```

First should create a view and save ids on that, then we can update our status with what id founded.